# beginner, using turtle forward, but the turtle all stop at different places

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am trying to create a race using turtle, but I've noticed that every time I launch the program the turtle stop to turn around at different places. Here is the code:

```
from turtle import Turtle
from random import randint
#creation of turtles
Ivo = Turtle()
Ivo.color("blue")
Ivo.shape("turtle")
Rirriuk = Turtle()
Rirriuk.color("yellow")
Rirriuk.shape("turtle")
Laura = Turtle()
Laura.color("red")
Laura.shape("turtle")
Ivo.penup()
Ivo.goto(-130, 22)
Ivo.pendown()
Ivo.pendown()
Rirriuk.penup()
Rirriuk.goto(-130,42)
Rirriuk.pendown()
Laura.penup()
Laura.goto(-130, 62)
Laura.pendown()
#random movement generator
for movement in range(100): 
    Ivo.forward(randint(1, 5))
    Rirriuk.forward(randint(1, 5))
    Laura.forward(randint(1,5))    
Ivo.right(180)
Rirriuk.right(180)
Laura.right(180)
for movement in range(50):
    Ivo.forward(randint(1, 5))
    Rirriuk.forward(randint(1,5))
    Laura.forward(randint(1,5))
```

anyone has an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're moving the turtles random distances, so you can expect different stopping points, right? Please state your expected behavior.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @ggorlen they are moving at a random distance, but shouldn't they all move until they reach distance 100?

Comment: No, they move random distances 100 times.

Comment: @ggorlen I thought differently. thank you. then I think I'll need to rewrite some things before asking for help again